# Show that slope of MR (marginal revenue) is negative for monopolists

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, monopoly

I want to show that the marginal revenue is negative for monopolists.

We assume $P(Q)$ is homogenous of degree 1, so it is linear (affine, strictly speaking): $P(Q)=a-bQ$.

As we know, $\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ} \lt 0$ because the slope of the demand curve is negative.

So $\overbrace{Q\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}+P(Q)}^{=MR} \lt P(Q)$ and $MR \lt P(Q)\ \forall \ Q \ge 0$.

So I want to show that the marginal revenue is not constant (as it is on a competitive market) but also decreases.

$$
\frac{dMR}{dQ}=\frac{d\bigl(Q\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}+P(Q)\bigr)}{dQ}=\frac{d\bigl(Q\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}\bigr)}{dQ}+\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}=2\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}.
$$

Is this approach correct and is it sufficient for showing that 1. the slope of MR will be negative for monopolists and 2. it will be exactly twice as great as the slope of the demand curve?
Is there a simpler/more logical explanation?

Comment: But if we have homothetic demand curves, the slope of the demand curve should be a constant shouldnt it? @Giskard

Comment: 1. This assumption is not stated in your question.

Comment: 2. What is a homothetic demand curve?

Comment: An affine transformation of an homogenous demand function of degree one? @Giskard

Comment: I think my assumption should be it's an affine demand curve $P(Q)=a-bQ$. @Giskard Sorry I forgot about that. So all of this would only hold for affine/linear demand functions?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/45651/edit) accordingly.

Comment: In this (special) case it is indeed true that
$$
MR(Q) = \frac{d\bigl(Q\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}\bigr)}{dQ}+\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ} = -2b < 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I reckon this will be an entirely different story for non-linear demand curves such as the one you proposed above? Or would there be a more general way of showing that $dMR/dQ$ is negative for monopolists? @Giskard Oh and I think you meant $dMR(Q)/dQ$, not $MR(Q)$?

Comment: Have you tried proceeding with the differentiation? Seems like using the product rule would yield results.

Comment: Hmm I got $\frac{d(Q\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ})}{dQ}+\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}=Q\biggl(\frac{\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}}{dQ}\biggr)+2\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}$ but I can't really make much of the second derivative on the left side. The only thing I know is that $dP(Q)/dQ$ is negative. But that doesn't tell me anything about the second derivate. @Giskard

Comment: @HerrK. We moved on to non-linear curves in [this comment](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/45651/show-that-slope-of-mr-marginal-revenue-is-negative-for-monopolists#comment74293_45651).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show
$$
\frac{dMR}{dQ} < 0.
$$
As you point out in the comments
$$
\frac{dMR}{dQ}= Q\frac{d^2P(Q)}{dQ^2} + 2\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}.
$$

**The linear case**

When $P(Q) = a - bQ$, assuming $a,b>0$, you get
$$
\frac{dMR}{dQ}= Q \cdot 0 - 2b = - 2b< 0.
$$

**The general case**

$$
Q\frac{d^2P(Q)}{dQ^2} + 2\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ} < 0
$$
does not hold for all decreasing functions $P(Q)$. A counterexample is $P(Q) = Q^{-2}$. 
In this case
$$
Q\frac{d^2P(Q)}{dQ^2} + 2\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ} = Q(-2)(-3)Q^{-4} + 2(-2)Q^{-3} = 2Q^{-3} > 0.
$$

**The concave case**

A sufficient (but not necessary) condition for downward sloping $MR(Q)$ is to assume that $P(Q)$ is strictly decreasing and concave. 
 In this case $\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}$ is negative and $\frac{d^2P(Q)}{dQ^2}$ is non-positive, so their (weighted) sum is negative, hence
$$
\frac{dMR}{dQ}= Q\frac{d^2P(Q)}{dQ^2} + 2\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ} < 0.
$$